# Alter xticks matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis

I have a scatter plot that has time on the `x-axis`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00','10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
    'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['A']
y = df['B']

x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())

plt.scatter(x_numbers, y)
plt.show()
```

Output 1:
[image]

I wanted to swap total seconds for actual timestamps so I included:

```
plt.xticks(x_numbers, x)
```

This results in the x-ticks overlapping each other.

If I use:

```
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)
```

The results is the same as above. If I change the `nbins` to something smaller the ticks don't overlap but they don't align with their respective scatter points. As in the scatter points don't line up with the correct timestamp.

If I use:

```
M = 10
xticks = ticker.MaxNLocator(M)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xticks)
```

The `ticks` don't overlap but the don't align with their respective scatter points.

Is it possible to pick the number of `x-ticks` you use but is still aligned to the respective data point.

E.g. For the `figure` below. Can I just use `n` number of `ticks` instead of all of them?

Output 2:

[image]

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. If ticks are close enough to each other, their labels will inevitably overlap. What kind of automatism would be able to prevent that?

Comment: I am trying to produce something similar to Output 1 but swap the x-ticks in seconds to timestamps. When I swap the timestamps the x-ticks frequency changes. Is there a way to use the same frequency as the initial output?

Comment: Output 1 is obviously a nice clean frequency. The x-ticks aren't overlapping each other or located at each data point. Why would it change when trying to insert timestamps? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use some xticklabel manipulations:

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00:00','08:10:00','08:12:00','08:26:00','08:29:00','08:31:00','10:10:00','10:25:00','10:29:00','10:31:00'],
    'B' : ['1','1','1','2','2','2','7','7','7','7'],     
    'C' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Y','Z','A','X','Y','Z'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

x = df['A']
y = df['B']

x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())

plt.scatter(x_numbers, y)
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
newlabels = [str(pd.Timedelta(str(i)+ ' seconds')).split()[2] for i in loc]
plt.xticks(loc, newlabels)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error `NameError: name 'xaxis' is not defined`

Comment: @Punter345 I left out `xaxis=ax.get_axis()`.

Comment: @Thanks for looking at this @Scott Boston. Instead of the `NameError`, I'm get a ValueError: `ValueError: unit abbreviation w/o a number`

Comment: Maypbe upgrade pandas and matplotlib.

Comment: No dice. Apparently it has something to do with `pd.to_timedelta`

Comment: This seems like a data issue.  Can you put data in questiob that duplicates this error?

Comment: I can't even get your Output. If I copy the exact code from above I return this error.

Comment: I'm using `pandas 0.19.2` and `matplotlib 2.2.2`

Comment: Thanks! @Scott Boston

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the time interval is not consistent.
Secondly, it's a high-frequency series.

In a general case, you won't be required to match the `xticks` corresponding to each entry. And, in those scenarios, you can exploit something like `plt.plot_date(x, y)` along-with tick `locators` and `formatters` like, `DayLocator()` and `DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')`.

Though for this very specific case where data is at minute level and few points are really close, the hack may be to try and play with the numeric Series you are using for x-axis, `x_numbers`. For increasing the gap between two points, I tried `cumsum()` and for eliminate overlapping to an extent, gave some `rotation` to `xticks`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

x = df['A']
y = df['B']

x_numbers = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds()).cumsum()

plt.scatter(x_numbers, y)
plt.xticks(x_numbers, x, rotation=50)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My dataset is a little different but it replicable to the example. I need the total seconds for another plot so can't play with those numbers. Thanks though @DEEPAK